# Using the same private key on both the client and Server side for a SSL connection

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am working on a board that collects environmental information and sends it's data back to a single server to be processed. The only connections to this server will be made by the boards that will eventually be put out into the field. Most of the development is done, but now I would like to try to secure all of the connections. Speed is critical because the data is real time sensitive and the board has a fairly small processor on it (8Mhz). Since I have such tight control over it all I would like to share the same private key between the WiFi Chip and the Java based server that is accepting the connections. This would hopefully allow me to decrypt and encrypt messages over SSL without having to go through the handshake process each time one of the boards connects. Correct?

I have been experimenting for a few days with no luck. But before I dig deep into the rabbit hole I wanted to make sure that this is even possible. Thanks, any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: Given the situation you're in, it sounds like symmetric encryption is more what you're looking for.  SSL is asymmetric and is designed for use in situations where you cannot physically control key distribution.

Comment: @Aurand - That doesn't sound too bad, supposing the security of the boards is controlled appropriately.  Note that verifying signatures probably should still be done, to prevent replay attacks and similar.  In any case, you might want to ask something similar on the [Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/?as=1) site.

Comment: @Aurand: SSL/TLS uses *symmetric* encryption. Asymmetric crypto is only used for authentication during the handshake.

Comment: actually ssl uses both asymmetric and symmetric. The public/private keys (asymmetric) are used to encrypt/decrypt the secret key (symmetric) between the 2 parties. Once the 2 parties have the secret key, they switch to symmetric encryption because it's faster and more secure.

Ben, since you have tight control of the environment, you need to just use a shared secret key. The public/private keys are useful on the open internet to allow 2 parties to send the secret key to each other. You are in a position to skip this step.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!! Unfortunately, I am forced to used SSL to communicate using the WiFi Chip, Connect One's CO2144 [link](http://www.connectone.com/?page_id=178) . It only supports SSL connections. However, do you think it would be possible to effectively encrypt the data ( 30 bytes ) and then send the encrypted data over an unsecured connection? All without too much of a performance hit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be confused regarding the whay SSL/TLS works.

During the handshake, the server presents its certificate (unless an anonymous cipher suite is used) to prove its identity to the client, and then agrees on shared keys (via the exchange of a pre-master secret) with the client. Once the handshake has completed, only shared keys are used for the encryption. (More details [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/20803/2435).)

The server's private key is used to prove its identity to the client (via its certificate). The purpose of this is to prevent MITM attacks.

Giving the server's private key to the client would achieve nothing but allowing any client to impersonate the server.

You can't really avoid the handshake, also you may be able to use session resumption if you make multiple successive connections.
You may also be able to use TLS PSK (Pre-Shared Keys) cipher suites (sharing the symmetric key, not the private key), but they're not available in the Oracle JSSE provider.

Comment: Thank you sir! Your link is way more helpful than what is on Wikipedia, Java Tutorials, the first 10 pages of google! Good Stuff. I tried to upvote, but sadly I cannot yet :(

Comment: [Here](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/3213/2435) is another link that may be of interest (about small SSL implementations). If your data is only 30 bytes, you could indeed it encrypt manually with the recipient's public key (this is smaller than the pre-master secret used in SSL). This can be OK in a controlled environment. However, as always, you need to be careful if you design your own security mechanism. (Most home-made protocols tend to be insecure.)